# Setting up a trust to an AD environment with DCs on premise and in Azure, how can I limit AD traffic to only the on-premise DCs?

Tags: active-directory, trust-relationship

We are setting up a trust between a stand-alone on-premise domain (DMZ from now on) and a corporate domain which is AD/AAD (synched) (CORP from now on) so that users from CORP can log into servers joined to DMZ. To be clear, they're on separate forests.

My intention is to set up an external, non-transitive trust from DMZ to CORP.

Now, the thing is - the CORP domain has two domain controllers on-premise, and two domain controllers as VMs in Azure... I would like to avoid having to add two firewall rules (one for the on-premise DCs, one for the Azure DCs.)
How could I limit any AD traffic from DMZ to CORP to only hit the on-premise CORP DCs, or would that not be desirable for any reason besides redundancy?

I'm guessing if possible this will have to do with the CORP AD configuration under sites and services, in which case I may have a few follow-up questions :)

Thanks in advance and apologies for the noob-ness.

Comment: I'm not sure why DC's in Azure would be reachable from an on-premises DMZ. If those DC's are for use in Azure, the global DNS records should not be registered (mnemonics).

Comment: This is an inherited setup. The cloud DCs are there for other azure VMs, but also with the stated purpose of improved redundancy... which doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me (it'd only be useful if all our on premise DCs go down, which would be incredibly unlucky)

Comment: Any DC may service clients. Typically if there is a branch office/location where a DC should only service local clients, DNS SRV records and same as parent records should not  be registered. If they are registered, that is how DC's advertise to any and ALL clients to use them for service. It's possible to influence traffic with site link costs and policy settings, but not control or prevent flow in a vanilla Windows environment without adopting some network control (firewall/IPSEC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  AAD you mean Azure AD, then you have nothing to worry about. AD and AAD are two completely different systems, they use an intermediate tool (AD connect) to sync data between them. Basically, your DNZ domain controllers will know nothing about AAD.

Comment: You're absolutely correct - maybe I should remove the mention of AAD for clarity...  The problem is that the CORP domain has four domain controllers - two of them on premise, two of them VMs on Azure. I've changed the question and edited the text so that's clearer (before it just said we had DCs on premise and on Azure).

Comment: You can control AD trust traffic with DNS SRV records for CORP DCs. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/28f8884f-c073-41e0-b2ee-0dbb2dff5a1f/forest-trust-dnsdcs-visibility?forum=winserverDS

Comment: Than you, those links are very useful. Both that and this link, which they led to indirectly, helped answer a few of the background questions I had:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/domain-locator-across-a-forest-trust/ba-p/395689